# `CDialog::SetWindowPos` crashing

Tags: mfc

If I call `CDialog::SetWindow` on a dialog constructed as follows: `CDialog *tmp=new CDialog(IDD_TEST, theParent);`, then it crashes. If I call, `CDialog *tmp=new CDialog(); tmp->Create(IDD_TEST, theParent);`, then it doesn't. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC is kind of funny that way. Creating a C++ object doesn't create a corresponding window; it's a two step process. Your second example does it exactly the way Microsoft intended, creating the C++ class and then creating the window it's supposed to control. If you try to call a window controlling function before the window exists, bad things will happen.

Comment: But what is the point of the `explicit CDialog(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL);` constructor if you have to pass those arguments into Create as well?

Comment: @Casebash, those are used with `DoModal` which does not take any parameters.